# Exception at Unmarshalling an XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I have a problem with reading a XML file via JAXB and generated objects based on a xsd. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I have already seen questions with the same error but unfortunately no solution suggestion has helped me.

About my System:
Macbook M1
Intellij idea Ultimate
Openjdk 19

Thanks already for your help.

Here is all you need

Code

```
public Aufgabe4(String path) throws JAXBException {
        File f = new File(path);
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        InvoiceList invoiceList = (InvoiceList) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(
                unmarshaller.unmarshal(f));
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 
unexpected element (URI:"my.namespace/Invoices", lokal:"invoice-list"). Expected elements are (none)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:693)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1098)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:527)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:509)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3079)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:637)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:146)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:188)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:172)
    at Aufgabe4.<init>(Aufgabe4.java:23)
    at Aufgabe4.main(Aufgabe4.java:15)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

XSD: https://pastebin.com/vPkqH75k
XML: https://pastebin.com/hiR3cjsy

It would be nice, to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Reading an XML file via **JAXB** and generated objects based on an XSD.

Use **JAXB** to generate Java classes from XML Schema file(s) using its **XJC** compiler. This solution uses a Maven project to invoke **XJC** using the [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme).

[Here](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.0/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-invoices-2.1.0-mvn-src.zip) is a Maven project named **Invoices** using the standard file layout. This project includes:

- An XML Schema file [Invoices.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/main/resources/Invoices.xsd) for the `Invoice` model
- An XML Sample file [Invoices01-1.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/test/samples/Invoices01-1.xml) for unmarshalling
- A JAXB *binding* file [Invoices.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/main/resources/Invoices.xjb) for configuration
- A JUnit test class [InvoicesTest.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/test/java/namespace/my/invoices/InvoicesTest.java) to verify (un)marshalling
- Sample XML [file(s)](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/test/samples) with `InvoiceList` data.
- The Maven POM file with `hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin`

```
Invoices
    src
        main
            java
            resources
                Invoices.xsd
                Invoices.xjb
                simplelogger.properties
        test
            java
                namespace/my/invoices/InvoicesTest.java
            resources
                jvmsystem.arguments
                jvmsystem.properties
            samples
                Invoices01-1.xml
    pom.xml
```

##### Execution

This is a stand-alone Maven project. You can run the test using:

```
mvn clean test
mvn compile exec:java
```

The **JAXB** classes are generated by this plugin using this project's [pom.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/project-pom.xml)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-no-header</arg>
                    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins</artifactId>
                        <version>${hisrc-basicjaxb.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and are generated to:

```
target/generated-sources/xjc/

namespace
└── my
    └── invoices
        ├── AddressType.java
        ├── BankDetailsType.java
        ├── BillingInfo.java
        ├── BillingType.java
        ├── Company.java
        ├── ContactType.java
        ├── CurrencyCodesType.java
        ├── CurrencyType.java
        ├── CustomerInfo.java
        ├── Customer.java
        ├── Invoice.java
        ├── InvoiceList.java
        ├── Items.java
        ├── ItemType.java
        ├── ObjectFactory.java
        ├── Other.java
        ├── package-info.java
        └── TaxesType.java
```

###### Approach

The [hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb#readme) is configured to generate **JAXB** classes using the provided [Invoices.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/main/resources/Invoices.xsd) schema. The schema provides the namespace `"my.namespace/Invoices"` which **JAXB** uses to create the Java `package` name using its own naming convention.

As an option, a more advanced implementation of Java's built-in `Object` methods are generated using these **XJC** [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme). In particular, the sample project uses the `toString` plugin to display *human-readable* representations of the unmarshaled `Invoice` objects.

**hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins**

```
<args>
    <arg>-no-header</arg>
    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
</args>
```

> *Note:* When the **XJC** [hisrc-basicjaxb-plugins](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) are used, the [hisrc-basicjaxb-runtime](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-basicjaxb#readme) dependency is required on the run-time class path.

###### Testing

The JUnit test class, [InvoicesTest.java](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/test/java/namespace/my/invoices/InvoicesTest.java), scans for the sample files and invokes the method `checkSample(File sample)` to provide each file to the tester. For this project, a `JAXBContext` is created and each file in the [samples](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/test/samples) path is *unmarshaled* to a `InvoiceList` object. When successful, each object is *marshaled* for logging and your [review](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/OUTPUT.txt).

###### Demonstration

A Java standard engine application with a constructor as provided by the OP and a `main(...)` method is at [`namespace.my.invoices.Aufgabe4`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/invoices/src/main/java/namespace/my/invoices/Aufgabe4.java).

```
public Aufgabe4(String path) throws JAXBException
{
    File f = new File(path);
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    InvoiceList invoiceList = (InvoiceList) JAXBIntrospector.getValue( unmarshaller.unmarshal(f));
    setInvoices(invoiceList);
}
```

This application is executed using:

```
mvn compile exec:java "src/test/samples/Invoices01-1.xml"
```